# to read xml using dom cencepts

Tags: vb.net

Iam doing XML reading using dom concepts, But i couldn't retrieve values correctly.

I want to RETRIEVE BELOW PART using for loop statement

```
<area id="508" Type="paragraph" visible="1" source_ap="True" invert="False" rotation="0" ignoretext="0">
      <pagename><![CDATA[11187_2014_06_14_000002_0004_NFHEZ]]></pagename>
      <pagenumber>1</pagenumber>
      <left>603</left>
      <top>868</top>
      <right>764</right>
      <bottom>1132</bottom>
      <polygon ispolygon="0" noofpoints="0"><![CDATA[]]></polygon>
   </area>
```

HERE IS THE FULL SAMPLE XML WHERE I WANT TO RETRIEVE USING FOR LOOP.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <articles>
 <template istemplate="true" twidth="0" theight="0" uwidth="0" uheight="0" ubottom="0">      </template>
   <article name="11187_2014_06_14_000002_0004_NFHEZ_00004" id="4">
      <articlename><![CDATA[11187_2014_06_14_000002_0004_NFHEZ_00004]]></articlename>
     <input_pages>
        <page name="11187_2014_06_14_000002_0004_NFHEZ" number="3">
          <pagepdfheight>1125</pagepdfheight>
        <pagepdfwidth>786</pagepdfwidth>
        <pagejpgheight>1125</pagejpgheight>
        <pagejpgwidth>786</pagejpgwidth>
        <pagejpgresolution>72</pagejpgresolution>
        <name><![CDATA[11187_2014_06_14_000002_0004_NFHEZ]]></name>
  <Article_Area>0</Article_Area>
  <Article_percentage>0</Article_percentage>
  </page>
  </input_pages>
  <NoOfPage>1</NoOfPage>
  <output_pages>
     <page number="1" height="0" width="0"/>
  </output_pages>
  <read>
     <area id="508" Type="paragraph" visible="1" source_ap="True" invert="False"            rotation="0" ignoretext="0">
        <pagename><![CDATA[11187_2014_06_14_000002_0004_NFHEZ]]></pagename>
        <pagenumber>1</pagenumber>
        <left>603</left>
        <top>868</top>
        <right>764</right>
        <bottom>1132</bottom>
        <polygon ispolygon="0" noofpoints="0"><![CDATA[]]></polygon>
     </area>
     <area id="507" Type="paragraph" visible="1" source_ap="True" invert="False" rotation="0" ignoretext="0">
        <pagename><![CDATA[11187_2014_06_14_000002_0004_NFHEZ]]></pagename>
             <pagenumber>1</pagenumber>
             <left>462</left>
             <top>868</top>
             <right>601</right>
             <bottom>1131</bottom>
        <polygon ispolygon="0" noofpoints="0"><![CDATA[]]></polygon>
     </area>
  </read>
```

My code is:

```
 Dim doc As New XmlDocument()
    Dim sValue, sPgName As String
    Dim sLeft, sTops, sRight, sBottom As String
    Dim ObjZoneInfo As CZoneInfo
    Try
        doc.Load(sFile)
          If doc.ChildNodes.Item(0).Name = "xml" Then
            If doc.ChildNodes.Item(1).Name = "articles" Then
                For i As Integer = 0 To doc.ChildNodes.Item(1).ChildNodes.Count - 1
                    If doc.ChildNodes.Item(2).ChildNodes.Item(i).Name = "article" Then
                        ObjZoneInfo = New CZoneInfo
                        For j As Integer = 0 To doc.ChildNodes.Item(2).ChildNodes.Item(i).ChildNodes.Count - 1
                            sValue = doc.ChildNodes.Item(1).ChildNodes.Item(i).ChildNodes.Item(j).InnerText


                            If doc.ChildNodes.Item(1).ChildNodes.Item(i).ChildNodes.Item(j).Name = "page_name" Then
                                If sProFiles.Contains(sValue) = False Then
                                    sProFiles.Add(sValue)
                                End If
                                ObjZoneInfo.PageName = sValue : sPgName = sValue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you are searching only for nodes with "area" tag, so try this:

```
Dim tagAreas as XmlNodeList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("area")
```

You can then use a For Each loop:

```
For Each tagArea as XmlElement in tagAreas Then

'______your code here. If you wanted to retrieve the "area" tag I don't understand the code you posted

Next
```

Now, to access attributes of the area nodes, you must use the following:

```
Dim area_id as Integer = Integer.parse(tagArea.GetAttribute("id")) 'if you want to obtain id data as integer
Dim area_type as String = tagArea.GetAttribute("type")
'so etc___________________
```

if you want to access the child nodes:

```
Dim area_pagenum as Integer = Integer.parse(tagArea("pagenumber"))
```

Comment: From Above code i can receive all tag but how to get below tag as separate value.                                                                    <area id="508" Type="paragraph" visible="1" source_ap="True" invert="False" rotation="0" ignoretext="0">  i need to get each as "area id,type,visible"

Comment: Check now, hope it helps.